# How to send Notification to Multiple device

Tags: python, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to do  crypto app that need to notify all user in same time.
Sending notification for single device worked for me. But how to send multiple device notification using python?

This Code send notification to single device only

```
import requests
import json   
serverToken = 'token here'
                
deviceToken = 'token here'

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=' + serverToken,
      }

body = {
          'notification': {'title': 'Sending push form python script',
                            'body': 'OMG lets goo1'
                            },
          'to':
              deviceToken,
          'priority': 'high',
        #   'data': dataPayLoad,
        }
response = requests.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",headers = headers, data=json.dumps(body))
print(response.status_code)

print(response.json())
```

(I just want to sent notification all user, who having flutter app)

**Edit**
I can make list of all device token but, is there anyway that sending notification who has my app.(without listing all device token)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. It is not possible to "help you" in general because we have no idea what help you need. We cannot explain how to solve the problem without any context. The best way is to show some code, explain what happens when you run the code, and explain what is supposed to happen instead and how that is different.

Comment: Okay, so you know how to write code that sends the message to one recipient. Do you know how to repeat code for each value in a list? Do you know how to put the recipients in a list? If you do those things, is the problem solved? If not, what actually is the problem? If you don't know these things, then you need to follow a Python tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals before trying to do anything this advanced.

Comment: Dear Karl Knechtel,
Thank for your kindness. I can loop it but the Device token may differ from other phones right?
Is there anyway to send notification to all user who has downloaded my app.

Comment: Well, do you know what all the device tokens are? Can you put those in a list? Then what?

Comment: Dear Karl,

This is the dart code to get device token,
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      print(token);

Let me put all in list as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to provide more context. Karl Knechtel's answer is important to consider. However, I will say that in *very general* terms, it seems asynchronous programming might be a solution. You might call an asynchronous function to alert all your members while running your functions. This would allow the program to continue running as normal, not slowed down by notifying multiple users, while running a separate asynchronous function to notify as many people you want.

Again: this is an *extremely* general solution to a problem that could very well not be the one you're experiencing, because you *really* need to provide sample code, context, and be clearer about what you need help with.

**Edit:**

Adding more for clarity and specificity.

*If the issue is you can't have your program delayed because it's notifying a large volume of recipients:*

Consider a structure like:

```py
async def alertMembers()

async def program()
```

In which you can *call* or `await` your program to alert all your members without disrupting the flow of the actual program.

*If the issue is that you don't know how to alert more than one member using whatever alert method you are:*

Consider a recipients list, read from a CSV or JSON, that your program iterates in a `for` loop to get to all the recipients. Like so:

```py
recipients = pd.read_csv('recipients.csv') # Using Pandas and CSV

with open('recipients.json', 'r') as f: # Using inbuilt JSON parsing
    recipientsJSON = json.load(f)

# Sample recipientsJSON dictionary:
recipients = {
    "John": ["19280120987"],
    "Mary": ["19283192832"]
}

# Executing with a for loop
for recipient in recipientsJSON:
    sms.send_message(
        "number": recipientsJSON[recipient][0]
        "content": 'something' # Your alert
    )
```

This type of a structure would execute quite efficiently and can handle any number of recipients.

These are some potential solutions to a very vague and unknown problem, so please edit, rephrase, and add context to your question so it can be answered appropriately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry i just add my code kindly check it out thk

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. I did not give an answer; I left a comment, because I felt the question could not be answered properly on Stack Overflow as asked. I advise that you do not attempt to give "a extremely general solution to a problem that could very well not be the one you're experiencing", because that is exactly what makes the question off topic for the site.